# Populate Django <select> <option>s from model's rows, not its CHOICES

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with a dozen rows.

Is there a shortcut to make a form with a `<select>` where a field from each row becomes an `<option>`.

I've Googled this, but all I find are ways to use a model's CHOICES tuple as the `<select>`.

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking, but maybe you want a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)?

Comment: Sorry, back-quoted HTML tags look fine in the preview, but don't display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). This is the default form field for foreign keys.

```
class MyForm(forms.formForm):
    my_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all())
```

By default `option`'s value will be the primary key, and the label will be given by the `__str__` method. But you can override this:

#### Use another field as value:

```
class MyForm(forms.formForm):
    my_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all(),
                                      to_field_name='foo')
    # Where foo is a field of `MyModel`.
```

#### Customizing the label

```
class MyCustomModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return '{} ({})'.format(obj.foo, obj.bar)

class MyForm(forms.formForm):
    my_field = MyCustomModelChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all())
```